# How to properly compile and install BitQuest Bukkit plugin?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to install the following plugin on my Minecraft Bukkit server (https://github.com/bitquest/bitquest). But for that I have to compile it first. I tried Maven `mvn package` because I didn't know what `make -B jar` meant in the manual. This resulted in a .jar file which then did not work on the server (it issued error messages). I hope you can help me. Kind regards jcjms.

Manual:

Building the BitQuest Java Plugin
You can build the bitquest Java plugin that you can drop in to a Bukkit server. This will enable all BitQuest features on your server.

1. Requirements

Java JRE+SDK (Version 1.8)
Maven

2. Compile BitQuest and generate a JAR file

```
make -B jar
```

This will create a BitQuest.jar in the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IntelliJ/Eclipse to compile it?

Download the sources from **src/main** and put them into a new project's **src** folder. Also, I've noticed that the author put the **plugin.yml** and **config.yml** into the **resources** folder. As far as I know, it should just be in the source folder, so move them into the **src** folder of the project. Then compile it (IntelliJ: build artifacts, Eclipse: export) and put it into your server's plugin folder. If there are no java errors, it should work.